# A Question in Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

We have 6 points in a 3*4 rectangle.prove that at least two points exist which their distance is less than $\sqrt2$.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Don't just ask us to do your homework for you.

Comment: i want to try but i don't know from where ?!

Comment: This isn't true. See @shn's answer for a good counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

You can chose 6 points whose distance is at least $\sqrt 2$ apart.
[image]

Comment: sorry but that's not a prove :)

Comment: @SeyedMoeinAyyoubzadeh It's not a proof, it's a *counterexample*: the statement you are trying to prove is **false**. Perhaps you meant "no greater than $\sqrt{2}$"?

Comment: note that you shouldn't choose your point on the rectangle itself.!!

Comment: @SeyedMoeinAyyoubzadeh You should clarify that in your question.

Comment: Even so, my rectangle is only $2\times 3$ and can easily be embedded in a $3\times 4$ rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

For another counterexample, take the points $(0;0)$, $(4;0)$, $(4;3)$, $(0;3)$, $(1.1;\ 2)$ and $(2.9;\ 2)$ in Cartesian plane.

Comment: note that you shouldn't choose your point on the rectangle itself.!!

Comment: Thus the points $(0.06;\ 0.07)$, $(0.07;\ 2.94)$,  $(1.21;\ 2)$, $(3.93;\ 2.94)$, $(3.91;\ 0.07)$ and $(2.78;\ 1.98)$ suffice. This can be easily checked using *Geogebra*, for instance.